# Не могу понять строку в базе данных

Tags: sql, postgresql

Не могу понять строку в базе данных. Вроде понимаю что переменной `$query` передаётся SQL команда `SELECT`, но вот что в написано в команде не пойму. Почему написано `с.name`, а потом `p.id` итд. Почему было сначала `с.что-то`, а потом стало `р.что-то`. И если не сложно укажите как данная команда бы выглядела для PostgresSQL

```
 $query = "SELECT
        c.name as category_name, p.id, p.name, p.description, p.price, p.category_id, p.created
    FROM
        " . $this->table_name . " p
        LEFT JOIN
            categories c
                ON p.category_id = c.id
    ORDER BY
        p.created DESC";
```

Comment: Перевод на человеческий того куска запроса: выбери поле name из таблицы с, которая называется categories,  поле id из таблицы р, которая называется " . $this->table_name . "

Comment: Это называется join и буквы `c.` и `p.` это alias для таблиц, таблица categories имеет alias `c`, а вторая таблица видимо products имеет alias `p` и в запросе селект указывается, что какие-то данные берем из категорий, а какие-то данные из таблицы продуктов.

Comment: А в postgres она выглядела бы так же, потому что SQL

Comment: @AidarSaifutdinov, прошу прощения, но я теперь не могу пометить что вопрос решён (ответ найден).

Comment: @Lem0nti, прошу прощения, но я теперь не могу пометить что вопрос решён (ответ найден).

Comment: @SanDisk добавил как ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это называется join и буквы `c.` и `p.` это alias для таблиц, таблица `categories` имеет alias `c`, а вторая таблица видимо `products` имеет alias `p` и в запросе SELECT указывается, что какие-то данные берем из категорий, а какие-то данные из таблицы продуктов.